# Create closure in Elixir

Tags: closures, elixir

I have a `Sequence` struct that consists of a `state` and a `generator` function which generates the new state from the old one. I want to write a `limit` function that returns a new sequence that should return the new state exactly `n` times at max and every `n + k` time it should return `nil`. The code so far is:

```
defmodule Sequence do
  defstruct [:state, :generator]

  def generate(%Sequence{state: nil}) do
    nil
  end

  def generate(%Sequence{state: state , generator: generator } = seq) do
    {old_state, new_state} = generator.(state) 
    { old_state,  %Sequence{ seq | state: new_state } }
  end

  def limit(%Sequence{ generator: generator } = seq, n) when n > -1 do
    lim_gen = create_limit_gen(generator, n)
    %Sequence{ seq | generator: lim_gen }
  end

  defp create_limit_gen(generator, n) do
    lim_gen = fn 
                  nil -> 
                    nil
                  _ when n == 0 -> 
                    nil
                  st ->
                    IO.puts(n) # no closure happens here
                    n = n - 1
                    generator.(st)
              end
    lim_gen
  end

end
```

I want to have the following results:

```
iex> seq = %Sequence{state: 0, generator: &{&1, &1 + 1}} |> Sequence.limit 2
iex> {n, seq} = seq |> Sequence.generate; n
0
iex> {n, seq} = seq |> Sequence.generate; n
1
iex> seq |> Sequence.generate
nil
iex> seq = %Sequence{state: 0, generator: &{&1, nil}} |> Sequence.limit 2
iex> {n, seq} = seq |> Sequence.generate; n
0
iex> seq |> Sequence.generate
nil
```

The problem is that the `IO.puts` prints always the same number, meaning it doesn't change. However my limit generator depends on that value and it changing in the closure. What is the problem here and how can I fix it ? Any help is welcomed :)

PS: I'm not allowed to add new fields to the structure and I don't want to use things like `GenServer` and `ETS`

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish, please elaborate a bit more. Also, have you tried changing `n = n - 1` to `st = n - 1`?

Comment: @Sheharyar changing `n` to `st` there won’t have any effect since the value is used once in call to `generator` and efficiently dropped afterwards. There is a need to pass the accumulator through, counting the attempts left (or, better, to use a `reducer`s as it’s done in the whole [`Stream`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/stream.ex) module.)

Comment: Is this just for learning purposes or are you writing an actual piece of software? In the latter case, I'd advise you to just use the `Stream` module.

Answer (score 7):

In most cases, it makes sense to create an MCVE to locate a problem and understand what’s going on. Let’s do it:

```
iex|1 ▶ defmodule Test do
...|1 ▶   def closure(n) do
...|1 ▶     fn  
...|1 ▶       _ when is_nil(n) or n == 0 -> IO.puts("NIL")
...|1 ▶       _ ->
...|1 ▶         IO.puts(n)
...|1 ▶         closure(n - 1).(n - 1) # or something else
...|1 ▶     end 
...|1 ▶   end 
...|1 ▶ end
```

OK, let’s test it:

```
iex|2 ▶ Test.closure(2).(2)  
2
1
NIL
:ok
```

Cool, it works as expected. Now let’s turn back to your code:

```
st ->
  IO.puts(n) # no closure happens here
  n = n - 1
  generator.(st)
```

The second line in the clause **has no effect at all**, since everything in *Elixir* is immutable. `n = n - 1` rebounds local variable `n` to the new value, but it’s dropped (GC’d) immediately after, since `generator` receives `st` and `n` is not used anymore anywhere.

The code is quite cumbersome, but I would suggest you don’t need to accumulate the current `n` in `create_limit_gen`, what you see currently is exactly how closures work: `n` is being assigned once, when a closure was created, and it does not change along time. To change it, one should change it explicitly, e.g. by passing `n` through (as shown in my first snippet for MCVE.)

Something like

```
generator.(n, create_limit_gen(generator, n - 1))
```

and proper handling the result should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to change the behaviour of my `generator` function. I don't want it to use two input parameters in the generate function. The generate function must stay the same. How can I achive this ?

Comment: If `generator` accepts the single value, having nothing to do with the limit, you should store the state somewhere (that said, you need an explicit `GenServer` for that, or ETS, or like.)

Comment: I think there should be a solution without using `GenServer` or `ETS`

Comment: Yes, and it’s called reducer, accepting _two_ parameters, one for real value and one for an accumulator. Check `Stream` module I have linked in the very first comment.

Comment: I loked at the file, but have no idea how to implement it. An example would be great thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you want to accomplish but I think it would be better to do it like this:

```
def limit(seq, n) when n > -1 do
  %Sequence{state: {seq.state, n}, generator: create_limit_gen(seq.generator)}
end

defp create_limit_gen(generator) do
  lim_gen = fn
    {nil, _} ->
      nil 
    {_, 0} -> 
     nil
    {state, n} ->
      {old_state, new_state} = generator.(state)
      {old_state, {new_state, n}}
  end
  lim_gen
end
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to add new fields to the structure.